# Legend from two different plots on one single plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

So if I run my code I am supposed to get a legend for both the plots but I am getting only for one. Can someone please give a solution. I want both plots in one graph but the separate legend command is not working. The code is as follow:

```
close all;clear all;clc

load stiffhless

figure
plot(FI*180/pi,ktot);
xlabel('\psi [deg]');ylabel('k');
title('Stiffness coeff. of flapping motion eq.')
xlim([0,360])
set(gca,'XTick',0:45:360) 
grid on
legendCell=strcat('\mu=',strtrim(cellstr(num2str(mu_vect'))));
legend(legendCell)
hold on

load stiffarti
plot(FI*180/pi,ktot,'--');
xlabel('\psi [deg]');ylabel('k');
title('Stiffness coeff. of flapping motion eq.')
xlim([0,360])
set(gca,'XTick',0:45:360) 
grid on
legendCell=strcat('\mu=',strtrim(cellstr(num2str(mu_vect'))));
legend(legendCell)
```

Comment: Set the legend after you've plotted both plots, as `legend(legendCell1, legendCell2)`.

Comment: Not working. Have tried.

Comment: Since I don't have access to `stiffhless` or `stiffarti`, I can't really verify this. Could you possibly create a [minimal, _complete_ and _verifiable_ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the same problem? It will help us help you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ICLjv0NFxrSlBNdGc5RVp2WDA/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ICLjv0NFxrQzVzdjNJbnBOZG8/view?usp=sharing these are links to the two files. Please see if you can access them.

Comment: Apologies, but I will not download and try these out; possibly someone else will. Again, I'll help you out if you can boil down your problem to a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (without links to external data sources). Did you read the link I provided in my previous comment? Again, following those guidelines will help us help you (and we want to help!). If you're looking for specific code review, possibly http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better forum.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I found a way out of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per @dfri's comments, it's easiest for us to help you if you can produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're having (in doing so, you may even solve the problem yourself!).

Carefully reading relevant MATLAB documentation ([legend](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html)) is also a great place to start when seemingly innocent commands aren't behaving the way you expect them to.

Those comments aside, here are two possible ways to include multiple legend entries:

---

**If you want to add all legend entries at once,** I believe this is a minimal version of your problem:

```
x=1:10; y=rand(1,10);
figure; plot(x,y);
legendCell='foo';
legend(legendCell);
hold on;
plot(x,-y);
legendCell='bar';
legend(legendCell);
```

If so, the second call to `legend` is overwriting the first call. In this case, @dfri's comment is exactly right -- this is what you mean to do:

```
figure; plot(x,y);
legendCell1='foo';
hold on;
plot(x,-y);
legendCell2='bar';
legend(legendCell1,legendCell2);
```

Or even better, no need for the `legendCell1/2` variables:

```
legend('foo','bar');
```

[image: only last legend entry] [image: both legend entries]

---

**If you need to add legend entries one at a time,** here's one method to do so:

```
figure; plot(x,y);
L=legend('foo');

hold on;
plot(x,-y);
L=legend(L.String,'bar');

plot(x,2*y);
L=legend(L.String,'boo');

plot(x,-2*y);
L=legend(L.String,'far');

...
```

Assigning a variable name `L` to the legend object allows you to get a list of all existing legend strings `L.String`. So, by calling `L=legend(...)` again, you can essentially add elements to the existing list.

Comment: Thanks for the help.